# Modeling in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, model

I'm trying to model a seashell using a bunch of polygons, for example as shown in: [link text](http://www.ma.iup.edu/projects/CalcDEMma/SeaShellCode.html)

But I am new to OpenGL.  How would I get started modeling this, and what would the procedure be like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are going to generate the geometry procedurally instead of "sculpting it".

What you need to do is to generate your geometry just like in the mathematics example and store your it in [vertex buffer objects](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) (VBO). There are multiple ways of doing this, but generally you will want to store you vertex information (position, normal, texture coords if any) in one buffer, and the way these vertices are grouped into faces in another (called an index array).

You can then bind these buffers and draw them with a single call to `glDrawElements()`.

Be careful that the vertices in the faces are all in the same winding order (counter-clockwise or clockwise) and the the winding order is specified correctly to OpenGL, or you will get your shell inside out!

VBOs are supported in OpenGL 1.4 and up. In the extremely unlikely event that your target platform does not support that (update your drivers first!) you can use [Vertex Arrays](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html). They do pretty much the same thing, but are slower as they get sent over the bus every frame.

Answer (score 0):

While modelling objects procedurally (i.e. generating coordinates as numbers in the code) may be OK for learning purposes, it's definitely not the thing you want to do, as it gets very impractical if you have anything more complicated than a few triangles or a cyllinder). Some people consider procedural generation an art, but you need a lot of practice to achieve nice-looking (not to mention, realistic) results with that approach.

If you want to display a more complex, realistic model, the approach is to:

- create the model in a modelling tool (like the free and powerful `Blender`)
- save it to a file in a given format,
- in your program, load the object from the file to memory (either to your RAM to display using *Vertex Arrays* or to your GPU memory directly using a *Vertex Buffer Object*) and display it.

Common format (though an old an inconvenient one) is `.obj` (Wavefront OBJ), Blender is able to save to that and you are likely to google an OpenGL OBJ loader (or you can roll your own - untrivial, but still easy).

An alternative is to create an export script for Blender (very easy, if you know Python) and save the model as a simple binary file containing vertices, etc; then load it in your application code very easily.